NIntegrate underestimate the area under the graph
I want to find the area under this graph,

I used NIntegrate for this purpose and here is my script,
theta1 = 34.9951;
f[u_, v_] := -1/(theta1)*
  Log[1 + ((Exp[-theta1*u] - 1)*(Exp[-theta1*v] - 1))/(Exp[-theta1] - 
       1)]
mu = 162.1899;
sigma = 63.4740;
normaldist = CDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]];
minim = 25;
maxim = 160;
NIntegrate[D[f[u, normaldist[v]], u] /. u -> 0.25, {v, minim, maxim}] 


But I got 41.247280167157980017 as a result. Which doesn't make sense.
I played with the upper bound of the integral number to find the problem. When I changed it from 160 to 130 the result decreased by 29.343400064878947881which is close to 30 and not so inaccurate. But the problem is in the integration from 25 to 130, which underestimates the result a lot. I thought maybe because the range of the integral is large it causes the problem, but I also tried to break the interval (25,160) into (25,30), (30,35),...,(155,160) and wrote a lot of NIntegrate functions, but the final result I got was 36.656733469210373430 and the problem persists.
I'm wondering how to fix this and calculate the integral accurately.

If you plot what you integrate it seems reasonnable

@chris I believe the image in my post is the plot of the function that I'm integrating. Did I make some mistakes?

If I change the 'NIntegrate' to 'Plot' I get:

Now the integration result looks reasonable.

Oh thanks for the help! Now I see that I made a terrible mistake as my function was D[f[u, normaldist[v+50]],u] And I forgot account for this shift in evaluating the integral.
